# django: Displaying database errors when debug = False

Tags: django, exception, error-handling, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework to perform get() post() on existing database. In the models, I haven't defined any primary or foreign key relations as these constraints are handled at database level. When I have `debug = True` in the settings.py file, the database level errors with traceback get displayed. However, when debug = False, I wish to display the errors in the response.

eg: error message:

```
IntegrityError at /dqf_api/ReceiptLog/
(1062, "Duplicate entry 'ede pivot-dummy-ede_case_76-ede pivot command 76' for key 'PRIMARY'")
```

When debug = True, this is displayed. When debug = False, how do I catch this error and display it?

**EDIT** : Including code modules

models.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRun(models.Model):
   # fields ..Doesn't have id field as the database doesn't have it
   class Meta:
      managed = False
      db_table = 'test_case_command_run'
      unique_together = (('team_name', 'suite_name', 'suite_run_id', 'case_name', 'command_name'),)


class TestCaseCommandRunResults(models.Model):
    # fields ..Doesn't have id field as the database doesn't have it
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'test_case_command_run_results'
        unique_together = (('suite_run_id', 'command_run_id', 'rule_name', 'result_id'),)
```

views.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet.objects.values('team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet

class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet.objects.values('suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id',
                                                           'result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values')
    serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet

class ReceiptLogViewSet(CreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.ReceiptLogSerializer.ReceiptLogSerializerClass
```

serializers.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet
        fields = ['suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name', 'result_id','result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values']

class TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TestCaseCommandRunSerializer
        fields = ['team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status']

class ReceiptLogSerializerClass(serializers.Serializer):
    team_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=30)
    suite_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
    suite_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default=datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S'))
    case_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    command_run_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50,required=False, allow_blank=True, default='Not Applicable')
    run_start = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=False)
    run_end = serializers.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, required=False)
    result = serializers.CharField(max_length=10, default='Not Applicable')
    run_status = serializers.CharField(max_length=10)
    rule_name = serializers.CharField( max_length=50, required=False, allow_blank=True,  default='Not Applicable')
    expected_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    actual_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    report_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)
    extended_values = serializers.CharField(max_length=200, allow_blank=True)

    def create(self, validated_data):
    team_name = validated_data.get('team_name', None)
    suite_name = validated_data.get('suite_name', None)
    suite_run_id = validated_data.get('suite_run_id', None)
    case_name = validated_data.get('case_name', None)
    command_name = validated_data.get('command_name', None)
    command_run_id = validated_data.get('command_run_id', None)
    run_start = validated_data.get('run_start', None)
    run_end = validated_data.get('run_end', None)
    result = validated_data.get('result', None)
    run_status = validated_data.get('run_status', None)
    rule_name = validated_data.get('rule_name', None)
    expected_values = validated_data.get('expected_values', None)
    actual_values = validated_data.get('actual_values', None)
    report_values = validated_data.get('report_values', None)
    extended_values = validated_data.get('extended_values', None)

    test_case_command_run_data = {
        'team_name': team_name,
        'suite_name': suite_name,
        'suite_run_id': suite_run_id,
        'case_name': case_name,
        'command_name': command_name,
        'command_run_id': command_run_id,
        'run_start': run_start,
        'run_end': run_end,
        'result': result,
        'run_status': run_status
    }
    TestCaseCommandRunSerializer.create(TestCaseCommandRunSerializer(), validated_data=test_case_command_run_data)

    test_case_command_run_result_data = {
        'suite_run_id': suite_run_id,
        'command_run_id': command_run_id,
        'rule_name': rule_name,
        'result_id':  self.result_id,
        'result': result,
        'expected_values': expected_values,
        'actual_values': actual_values,
        'report_values': report_values,
        'extended_values': extended_values,
    }
    TestCaseCommandRunResultsSerializer.create(TestCaseCommandRunResultsSerializer(), validated_data=test_case_command_run_result_data)

    self.result_id += 1
    return validated_data
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'test_case_command_runs', views.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet)
router.register(r'test_case_command_run_results', views.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^dqf_api/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^dqf_api/ReceiptLog/', views.ReceiptLogView.ReceiptLogViewSet.as_view(), name='ReceiptLog')]
```

**EDIT: code Fix**

Added this to serializers.py

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    try:
        return super().create(validated_data)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        error_msg = "IntegrityError occurred while creating entry in test_case_command_run_result model. Detailed Error: %s" %e
        raise serializers.ValidationError(error_msg)
```

Comment: Post your code for further reference

Comment: Added code modules in the question

Comment: Edited my answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

Using a try catch statement
In views.py

```
class TestCaseCommandRunViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    try:
        queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet.objects.values('team_name','suite_name','suite_run_id', 'case_name','command_name','command_run_id','run_start','run_end','result','run_status')
        serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunViewSet
        return Response("working")
     except Exception as e:
        return Response(e)

class TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    try:
        queryset = models.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet.objects.values('suite_run_id','command_run_id','rule_name','result_id','result','expected_values','actual_values','report_values','extended_values')
        serializer_class = serializers.TestCaseCommandRunResultsViewSet
        retutn Response("Working")
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(e)
class ReceiptLogViewSet(CreateAPIView):
    try:
        serializer_class = serializers.ReceiptLogSerializer.ReceiptLogSerializerClass
        return Response("working")
    except Exception as e:
        return Response(e)
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? Added code modules in the question.

Comment: I tried this..this doesn't work. 
error:`django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1452, 'Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails ('ededqf'.'test_suite', CONSTRAINT 'fk_test_suite__team' FOREIGN KEY ('team_name') REFERENCES 'team' ('team_name'))')`

I want this to be shown in postman, instead it shows 500 internal server error

Comment: It seems like your are updating a foreign key field.

Comment: yes I am running into multiple issues with foreign key. However, I fixed the error by including create() in serializers.py...Added code snippet in question

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
if serializer.is_valid():
    serializer.save()
    return Response("success")
else:
    return Response(serialzier.errors)
```

Comment: Where should I add this code? Added code modules in the question.

Comment: Inside view, by overriding the POST request handler (/as per your business logic)